# C# Square brackets for accessing Objects with String

Tags: c#, .net

I don't understand this square brackets, what i have to create, that this code line is working, only for testing.

```
        filetype = dataBandREP["VRZ.Parent.SIGNATUR"].ToString();
```

Comment: `[...]` is indexer with `string` argument

Comment: Read up on [using-indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets mean you are referencing a collection and within that collection, you want "VRZ.Parent.SIGNATUR". `[]` is an indexer with a string as argument.

Answer (score 3):

C# can overload operator, including square brackets.

```
public class Example
{
    public string this[string s] // square bracket operator with string argument
    {
        get 
        {
            return somethingToReturnString;
        }
        set
        {
            somethingToSetString = value;
        }
    }

    public string this[int i] // square bracket operator with int argument
    {
        get 
        {
            return somethingToReturnInt;
        }
        set
        {
            somethingToSetInt = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:
`filetype = dataBandREP["VRZ.Parent.SIGNATUR"].ToString();`
uses the indexer of some sort of collection, referring to an object, then converting it to its string format in order to populate the filetype variable.

A very common usage of this is with arrays and `DataColumn` collections.  String indexers allow you to fetch a value based on, say, a column header, instead of knowing what integral index in the `DataTable.Columns` collection is associated with the column.

You're getting different behavior when debugging because the validity of `"VRZ.Parent.SIGNATUR"` as a string indexer has changed, probably because of a change in the actual data source.  That's assuming that you're getting a null reference or similar.  Without knowing what exception you're getting, we can't help much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Below syntax also works.. my class is derived from a ReadOnlyDictionary of some type "AttributeValue" and it exports double values. It gives the user an error box when 
the value is not found.

```
public abstract class AttribDoubleReader: IReadOnlyDictionary<string, AttributeValue>
{
 public double this[string key] => GetValue(key);

 private double GetValue(string key)
 {
    if (TryGetValue(key, out AttributeValue value))
    {
        return value.AsDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: KEY "+ key + " NOT FOUND.");
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }

 }
}
```